# Making the actionBar Cool

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

How can i make the ActionBar Epic as this one ? 
Also normally in Google Apps, when we swipe down the action bar actually get shrinked down in size with a beautiful effect, is that effect available for developers? or we have to do it on our own ? And how can we do it?

In this image overhere, there's icon and text above the image, and also a rounded button, i wonder if this sample is documented and i'm missing it, hope guys you'll point that out! 
Also how can they add text to the ActionBar??

Hope you'll help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Look at the extensive set of new APIs in the Android "L" SDK for Material Design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all from the new Materials Theme that is going to be available in the next version of Android.  You can find out more at the [Android L Developer Preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html) site.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) project available on github to implement your epic actionbar.

Regarding icons/buttons, simply use drawables or 9-patch to get it done.